# Use HTML 5 data-attributes for left and right directional values

Tags: jquery, animation

The following blocks of code are pretty much the same... the main diffirence between them would be the left and right directional values.

I would like to reduce the following code as much as possible, by possibly reusing one block of code for both .forward & .backward. I assume that we can use variables or the html5 data-attr to store values for left and right???

Thanks again everyone!

```
<div class="hover-area">
    Hover area
    <div class="backward">Backward</div>
    <div class="forward">Forward</div>
</div>

<style>
    a
.hover-area {
    position: relative;
}

.forward,
.backward {
    position: absolute;
}

</style>
```

​

```
    $('.forward').css({opacity:0, right:0});
    $('.hover-area').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.forward').stop()
            .animate({right:20}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
            .animate({opacity:'0.95'}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});
    },function() {
        $(this).find('.forward').stop()
            .animate({right:0}, {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'})
            .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'});
    });



    $('.backward').css({opacity:0, left:0});
    $('.hover-area').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.backward').stop()
            .animate({left:20}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
            .animate({opacity:'0.95'}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});
    },function() {
        $(this).find('.backward').stop()
            .animate({left:0}, {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'})
            .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'});
    });
```

Comment: Hi Taylor. After looking into this, my thought is that if you were to simplify any further, you would sacrifice a lot of readability of the code. I'll leave my 2 jsfiddles here http://jsfiddle.net/mk4AN/ and http://jsfiddle.net/mk4AN/1/ in case you or others want to play around with this. The 1st link is your original code and the 2nd is my attempt at simplifying (or in my opinion, overcomplicating). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the heck, I played with it a little and came up with:

```
$('.forward, .backward').css([$(this).is('.forward')?'right':'left'], 0).css('opacity', 0);
$('.hover-area').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(evt) {
    $(this).find('.forward, .backward').each(function(i,elm) {
        var direction = {};
            direction[$(elm).is('.forward') ? 'right' : 'left'] = evt.type==='mouseleave'?0:20;
        $(elm).stop()
            .animate(direction, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
            .animate({opacity: evt.type==='mouseleave'?0:0.95}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});
    });
});​
```

[**DEMONSTRATION**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Kv8cK/)

Comment: Very impressive!  +1 (Once I have my votes back again as I'm out for the day)